# What type is the typical "w" in Tkinter?

Tags: tkinter

Some typical basic code for Tkinter would be:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

w = Canvas(master, width=200, height=100)
w.pack()

w.create_line(0, 0, 200, 100)
w.create_line(0, 100, 200, 0, fill="red", dash=(4, 4))

w.create_rectangle(50, 25, 150, 75, fill="blue")

mainloop()
```

I can't find this in documentation, but I'm assuming w is a variable.  What type is it? Or does it have something to do with classes?

Answer (score 1):

In the code you post, `w` is simply a variable holding a reference to an instance of the Canvas class.

Comment: Can w be a global variable?  Even I put everything after master = Tk() was in a main() function (omitting the mainloop()), I get an error 'NameError: global name 'w' is not defined'

Comment: Yes, it can be a global. There is absolutely nothing special about this variable.